# Can I download minicom application on Windows?

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am trying to download minicom for a FreeRTOS project that I am working on in eclipse with STM32 microcontroller. The minicom application is supposed to allow me to read in keyboard input but it is available for MacOS. 
Is there a way that I can download it onto Windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You just need a serial terminal for windows.

You have a lots of free choices:

Putty, Realterm etc etc. Download and use.

Comment: thank you!so should I follow something like this? just set up the putty connection first and then minicom? http://labs.isee.biz/index.php/Using_serial_debug_port_to_communicate

Comment: this article is for IGEP boards so will it work for other microcontrollers like stm32?

Comment: not available choices for running inside CMD or Powershell